# How to get the xeditable select2 option working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, x-editable

I'm using the gem 'bootstrap-x-editable-rails' in a Rails 4 application.  I have an edit link that when clicked, enables the x-editable functionality.  Basic input field updates are working with xeditable.  However, when I try to update a serialized text field via select2 input field, "user_tags", a progress loading circle is displayed.  So I'm having 2 problems:

1)  Displaying the select options themselves

2)  And then figuring out how to update the serialized text field, where I want to store multiple tags in the same database column such as "Obi Wan", "Han", "Leia".

```
<a data-model='' data-name='user_tags' data-pk='135' data-source='[{"id":1,"text":"Obi Wan"},{"id":2,"text":"Kenobi"}]' data-title='title' data-type='select2' data-url='http://localhost:3000/1/starwars/135/saber_update' data-xeditable='true' href='#' id='user_tags'></a>
```

If I got #1 working, I could probably tackle #2.  Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?  I'm following the [x-editable docs](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) using the select2 data-* html attributes..